# Unity project build issue

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine, sdk

I'am trying to build an unity project for android , but I always get this issue.
[image]

When I click on "Update Android SDK" - > 
[image]

When I Click on " Use Highest Installed" -> [image]

In Unity is my SDK -> [image]

and my SDK Manager is from Android Studio -> [image]

Only solution is if I export the package and than import again , but it's very embarrasing because I have to set up again my project.
What's the solution for my problem?

Comment: Usually it's a path issue.  I see your path's are correct but just for the heck of it try changing your forward slashes to backslashes or vice-versa.

Comment: I tried to copy the sdk file from this location and than paste it in an another folder but it's not the solution :/ yesterday i have implemented the google admob in my project , can it have maybe this effect for my path? because the only solution is if I import the package again in an another unity project , but when I restart the PC the issue come back :/

Comment: I'm assuming you had to install the android module via unity hub to get this far, if so if it were me I would do a reinstall on the android module/android studio